# Class-Definition Comparison

Tags: javascript, prototypal-class-design, typescript

Whenever I needed something similar like a "Class" in JavaScript, I wrote it like this:

```
function Point(x, y){
    var self = this;
    self.x = x;
    self.y = y;
    self.dist = function(){
        return Math.sqrt( (self.x*self.x) + (self.y*self.y) );
    }
}

var p = new Point(10, 20);
p.x = 30;
alert(p.dist);
```

I declared a function and wrote the constructor directly into it. Public variables and methods have the `self.`-operator in front of it.

Now I took a look at TypeScript, which declares the exact same function this way:

```
var Point = ( function(){
    function Point(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    Point.prototype.dist = function(){
        return Math.sqrt( (this.x*this.x) + (this.y*this.y) );
    }
    return Point;
})();

var p = new Point(10, 20);
p.x = 30;
alert(p.dist());
```

This definition makes use of a closure, and uses `prototype`.

**My Questions:**

- What are the advantages/disadvantages of the 2 definitions?
- Which method is more efficient?
- Which method should I prefer to use (when I don't use TypeScript)?

Comment: This question seems offtopic, and there many duplicates on StackOveflow. Bottomline, the first one duplicates methods for each new instance, while the second one shares prototype methods between instances.

Comment: Agreed. I'd just add that the IIFE in the second example is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Using prototype is useful for polymorphism. If you want to create another class, eg. `ColourfulPoint`, you can use this code:

   `ColourfulPoint.prototype = Object.create(Point.prototype);`

   to make your new class inherit all the methods of `Point`.
2. The first method (using only a constructor) is **a way** faster (at least in Firefox and Chrome) than the prototype one. Take a look at the [test](http://jsperf.com/construct-proto).
3. Unless you intend to create polymorphic classes, use the first one.

Comment: That's really a huge performance difference. Now I'm not sure anymore, if switching/porting to TypeScript is the best choice

Comment: But in another test by @DaggNabbit, prototype reaches similar results or even wins: http://jsperf.com/construct-proto/2 - strange...

Comment: @maja check this in chrome!  http://jsperf.com/construct-proto/8